# Base word stemming instead of root word stemming in R

Tags: r, nlp, stemming

Is there any way to get base word instead of root word in stemming using NLP in R?

Code:

```
> #Loading libraries
> library(tm)
> library(slam)
> 
> #Vector
> Vec=c("happyness happies happys","sky skies")
> 
> #Creating Corpus
> Txt=Corpus(VectorSource(Vec))
> 
> #Stemming
> Txt=tm_map(Txt, stemDocument)
> 
> #Checking result
> inspect(Txt)
A corpus with 2 text documents

The metadata consists of 2 tag-value pairs and a data frame
Available tags are:
  create_date creator 
Available variables in the data frame are:
  MetaID 

[[1]]
happi happi happi

[[2]]
sky sky

>
```

Can I get base word "happy" (base word) instead of "happi" (root word) for "happyness happies happys" using R.

Comment: not sure about R specifically, but in general you need a morpological analyzer, for example you can get this OS one: http://seman.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/seman/trunk/Docs/Morph_UNIX.txt?revision=124&view=markup

Comment: Most probably you are not interested in stems, you want instead a lemmatizer. hmmm i could share with you my own open lemmatizer for english if you require that. but it's written in python...

Answer (score 2):

You're probably looking for a stemmer.
Here are some stemmers from [CRAN Task View: Natural Language Processing](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/NaturalLanguageProcessing.html):

- [RWeka](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RWeka/index.html) is a interface to Weka which is a collection of machine learning algorithms for data mining tasks written in Java. Especially useful in the context of natural language processing is its functionality for tokenization and stemming.
- [Snowball](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Snowball/index.html) provides the Snowball stemmers which contain the Porter stemmer and several other stemmers for different languages. See the Snowball webpage for details.
- [Rstem](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rstem/index.html) is an alternative interface to a C version of Porter's word stemming algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Without a good knowledge of English morphology, you would have to use an existing library rather than create your own stemmer.

English is full of unexpected morphological surprises that would affect both probabilistic and rule-based models. Some examples are:

- Removing an *in-* prefix to remove an *-able* suffix, as in *inhabitable*.
- Change of the word's category, as in the noun *bicycle* resulting from stemming the verb *bicycling* (can affect rules based on categories).
- Words with negative meanings cannot take negative prefixes (you can have *unpretty*, but not *unugly*).
- Two words as a compound, as in "truck driver" (you would treat them as one word when you stem).

English also has an issue with I-umlaut, where words like men, geese, feet, best, and a host of other words (all with an 'e'-like sound) cannot be easily stemmed. Stemming foreign, borrowed words, like *automaton*, may also be an issue.

Stemming the superlative form is a good example of exceptions:

best -> good

eldest -> old

A lemmatizer would account for such exceptions, but would be slower. You can look at the Porter stemmer rules to get an idea of what you need, or you can just use its SnowballC R package.

Answer (score 0):

`stemCompletion` could be used here. It's not the best one but manageable.

```
Stemm = tm_map(Txt, stemCompletion, dictionary=Txtt)
inspect(Stemm)

A corpus with 2 text documents

The metadata consists of 2 tag-value pairs and a data frame
Available tags are:
  create_date creator 
Available variables in the data frame are:
  MetaID 

[[1]]
happyness happies happies

[[2]]
sky sky
```

Comment: stemCompletion is time consuming task, is there any alternative to get same words? Please someone help for this.

Answer (score -1):

When I needed to do something similar, I wrote out my list of words in a text file, and fed it to the English Lexicon Project's web query tool, then parsed the result back into R. A little clunky, but lots of good data is available from ELP. 
For your use, Check out ELP's MorphSP.  For happiness, it gives {happy}>ness>

http://elexicon.wustl.edu/query14/query14.asp