# How to use stemDocument in the R language tm (text mining) package?

Tags: java, r, stemming

I am trying to stem a Corpus using stemDocument in the R language tm package which calls Java. 
I have tried the example in the tm manual:

```
data("crude")
crude[[1]]
stemDocument(crude[[1]])
```

and get the following error:

```
Could not initialize the GenericProperitiesCreator.  This exception was produced:  
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Any help appreciated.  I know nothing about Java.

Thanks

Comment: Works for me, must be something with your Java installation (you have Java installed, right?).

Answer (score 1):

Good question, did you work it out?

I get the same error with the only the code that you have. But if you follow the example from the start (ie. at the heading 'transformations on [p. 1](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm/vignettes/tm.pdf)) and you create a corpus and convert it to a Plain Text Document then you avoid the Java error. I guess that the code example in the [manual](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm/tm.pdf) assumes you've already done those two steps.

That said, when I inspect the results, there's no actual stemming... I can't even get @user813966's [simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6664556/base-word-stemming-instead-of-root-word-stemming-in-r) of stemDocument to do any stemming. I'm looking at the RStem and SnowBall packages instead.

In the meantime, the [python package NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/Home) is my stemming tool.

**Update**: I got the stemDocument function working by adding `language = "english"` as follows:

```
a <- tm_map(a, stemDocument, language = "english")
```

So the complete answer to your question is to follow all the steps of inputting your text into R according to the tm package. You'll also need rJava (and to set environment variables for JAVA_HOME to the directory containing the jre directory if you're working in windows) to make stemDocument work

Answer (score 1):

I had same error on my side. Solved it by adding the Snowball .jar and the corresponding /words repository of stem words in my class path:
C:\Users\xxx.xxx\Documents\R\win-library\2.12\Snowball\java

This was recommended here: http://weka.wikispaces.com/Stemmers

I still have the following error but it works fine now:

```
Trying to add database driver (JDBC): RmiJdbc.RJDriver - Warning, not in CLASSPATH?
Trying to add database driver (JDBC): jdbc.idbDriver - Warning, not in CLASSPATH?
Trying to add database driver (JDBC): org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver - Warning, not in CLASSPATH?
Trying to add database driver (JDBC): com.mckoi.JDBCDriver - Warning, not in CLASSPATH?
Trying to add database driver (JDBC): org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver - Warning, not in CLASSPATH?
[KnowledgeFlow] Loading properties and plugins...
[KnowledgeFlow] Initializing KF...
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this.  I tried to follow the same instructions, and I get the same error that you posted.  However, I the text is not stemmed. I think I might be missing a step. When you say that you add the corresponding /words repository, what is that? is that included in the \Snowball\java as well?

Answer (score 1):

Snowball stemmer (snowball.jar) cannot find the weka.jar file.

On your computer, you need to search for a file called weka.jar . On my linux system, it is located in

> /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RWekajars/java/weka.jar

Then, in your R code, add lines similar to these at the top:

```
wekajar="/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RWekajars/java/weka.jar"
oldcp=Sys.getenv("CLASSPATH")
newcp=NULL
Sys.setenv(CLASSPATH=paste(wekajar,newcp, sep=":"))

library("tm")    
data("crude")
stemDocument(crude[[1]], language = "english" )
```

This sets the Java CLASSPATH for the R Session to the weka.jar file from above . Your existing classpath will be reset, though. You can try to add the old entries back if you have some , and if you need them.